# How to create imageviews dynamically on runtime?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-relativelayout

Im building an android app which needs to create max of 1-4 imageviews depending on the number of images i need to display on the screen. I have written a small code but it doesn't seem to divide the screen equally on to 4 imageviews though. The top 2 are a little larger than the bottom two in my case. Following is my code i really cant think what the issue is

```
private void CreateScreen()
{
    int screenHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    int screenWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

    int matrixN = 2;

    int maxWForEachScreen = screenWidth / matrixN;
    int maxHForEachScreen = screenHeight / matrixN;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutFullScreen);

    ImageView imgView1 = new ImageView(LiveViewer.this);
    ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(LiveViewer.this);
    ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(LiveViewer.this);
    ImageView imgView4 = new ImageView(LiveViewer.this);

    int size = 3;

    if(size >= 3 && size <= 4)
    {
        imgView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        imgView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        imgView3.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        imgView4.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params4 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);

        params1.height = maxHForEachScreen/2;
        params1.width = maxWForEachScreen/2;

        params2.height = maxHForEachScreen/2;
        params2.width = maxWForEachScreen/2;

        params3.height = maxHForEachScreen/2;
        params3.width = maxWForEachScreen/2;

        params4.height = maxHForEachScreen/2;
        params4.width = maxWForEachScreen/2;

        params1.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        params2.setMargins(maxWForEachScreen/2, 0, 0, 0);
        params3.setMargins(0, maxHForEachScreen/2, 0, 0);
        params4.setMargins(maxWForEachScreen/2, maxHForEachScreen/2, 0, 0);

        relativeLayout.addView(imgView1, params1);
        relativeLayout.addView(imgView2, params2);
        relativeLayout.addView(imgView3, params3);
        relativeLayout.addView(imgView4, params4);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use table layout or grid layout.

Comment: Use `getSize(Point)` instead of `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`. They have been deprecated. What integer values do you get for `maxWForEachScreen` and `maxHForEachScreen`?

Comment: @Vikram elaborate more please?

Comment: What's wrong in using a relative layout and I dont see the point in using a grid layout either. @Vikram i get legit values for the screen width and height which is 1280 and 720. I think it's something to do with the layout params or because may be the bottom ImageView fits with according to the remaining space

Comment: @Mr.Noob Please take a look at my post below.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the weightsum of the parentLayout equal to the number of views.. And set 1 as weight of every view...This will make each views occupy equal space..